# Pie chart Reports in AX 2009

Tags: report, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009, x++, ax

Is it possible to create a pie chart report in AX 2009 Standard reports?

Comment: If you find an answer useful then please accept it.

Answer (score 1):

As I know, the answer is 'No', but you can:

- Add pie chart to form as ActiveX
- Use SSRS (or any other reporting tool you like)
- Generate pie chart bitmap (with helps some external program) and insert this bitmap on your report

Comment: SSRS is probably the best option, see http://www.youtube.com/user/dynamicsaxbi/videos?query=charting